# Get only date and give only date as input to react-date-picker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I am using [reat-date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker) package and I am in a situation where I want to give input only in date format like **09/23/2020** to `reat-date-picker` and save the selected value in the same format i.e. **03/22/2020**. But if we give only date as input to `reat-date-picker` it is giving below error. Someone help me out. Please refer to the sandbox link.

```
Failed to get month from date:
```

Reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-forked-rz7c0?file=/src/index.js

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Issue solved.

Reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-forked-rz7c0?file=/src/index.js

Thank you.